# How to upgrade Vue version

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, webpack

I was using the Vue version (2.5), I ran that command `npm install -g @vue/cli` after that I check my vue version by using the command `vue --version`and it shows me `@vue/cli 4.1.2`. but in my package.json file the version did not upgrade, it still showing me the older version i.e 2.5.7. 
[image]

Any help would be highly appreciable

Comment: Don't confuse the actual library/framework `vue` with the command line tool to manage projects `@vue/cli`.

Comment: @Mario How would one update the vue version of the project dependencies?

Comment: @OrestesKappa Just `install` `vue` at the version you want or just use `npm install vue@latest --save` to get the latest (note that updating from 2 to 3 requires quite some changes and many extensions haven't been updated yet).

Answer (score -13, accepted):

```
npm install -g @vue/cli --save
```

### --save will automatically update version in your package.json file.

Answer (score 25):

You can upgrade it through vue cli.

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

OR

```
yarn global add @vue/cli
```

then

```
vue upgrade
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` classic javascript dev tools

Comment: Too bad that `vue upgrade` just yields `Seems all plugins are up to date.`, even though this is a 2.5.* project. So this does not work at all.

Answer (score 3):

Both provided answers assume you have a project and you're updating it.
If you want to update the global installation, as per the documentation in the Vue website at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html
you need to do the following:

```
npm update -g @vue/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this guide to upgrade to Vue 2.7:
[Vue 2.7 Migration Guide](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-2-7-naruto.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use npx to avoid installing the @vue/cli package globally.

`npx --legacy-peer-deps @vue/cli upgrade`

Answer (score -2):

You can upgrade it through vue cli.

`yarn global add @vue/cli@3.0`

OR

`npm i -g @vue/cli@3.0`

then

`vue upgrade`